# Storing PHP session.upload_progress data in the database

Tags: php, session, file-upload, progress, php-7

Using session_set_save_handler in PHP 5.4.40, I have created a session handler that works well  ...except for session.upload_progress data when uploading a file.

My session handler completely ignores upload progress data, and I can only seem to get the progress data to save at all when:

- session.save_handler=files; and
- the session file is saved in the same path as session.save_path

Is it possible to save session.upload_progress data in the database?

**Update**: as at PHP 7 this still appears to be an issue. I have therefore opened [PHP 7 Bug #74131](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74131)

Answer (score 0):

The php documentation says this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php):

> Warning: The web server's request buffering has to be disabled for this to work properly, else PHP may see the file upload only once fully uploaded. Servers such as Nginx are known to buffer larger requests.

So what you want to do may be impossible...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure i understand: The progress data writes perfectly to file - why would a different write destination make any difference?

Comment: okay that fine so. If you can write it to a file you can write it to a database! I thought you couldn't access the information.

Comment: yep, session.upload_progress data writes to the "normal" /tmp/sess_..." file but completely ignores my session handler. So the upload data writes 100% to a file, but does not write to the database. So if I'm using my session handler, $_SESSION returns all session information EXCEPT session.upload_progress data. If there is no way to correct this problem then as far as I can see session.upload_progress handling does not behave in an aligned way with normal $_SESSION handling and renders the PHP file upload mechanism useless for "greater than 1" web server environments.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm dealing with this now, trying to get session.upload_progress to work while using $_SESSIONS in my database.

Comment: @eric - sorry, frustratingly, as far as I'm aware as at PHP 5.6.8 this problem is still not resolved - if anyone knows different please!

Comment: @eric - did you ever come right with this? We are upgrading to 7.0 and I am STILL seeing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

@Pancho I switched to use PECL uploadprogress. Works fine. Have to use mod_php and not fastcgi/fpm. User sessions are all in the db.

Comment: thanks for letting me know Eric! What version of PHP are you running? Is it 7.x or still 5?

Comment: running 5.6.xxx

Comment: thanks very much Eric - Our APCu approach is also working 100% on 5.6; Sadly it's 7 I'm struggling with (check out the bug/issue I opened on PHP above if interested - and feel free to vote the issue as important to help get traction if you agree that it is :) )