# PHP 5.4 - reliably interrogate session.upload_progress information

Tags: php, ajax, session, file-upload, apc

Most of the advice I see says to use the following configuration value for session.upload_progress data

> session.upload_progress.cleanup=on

From what I can see the result of this approach is that `$_SESSION["upload progress key"]` is erased immediately on completion of the upload, effectively wiping out all the data related to the completed file upload.

As one is running a separate XHR process to poll this data and display a progress bar, if the file being uploaded is very small, it is conceivable that the separate XHR thread only polls after the file upload has completed and the data has been removed.

I have 2 questions for proponents of the instantaneous deletion of data on completion of upload approach:

- If no data is found on the first XHR poll, is there a way one can reliably identify whether the file has finished uploading successfully, or whether something has gone wrong and the upload has not in fact started.
- Even if 1 or more polls has run during the upload successfully, on the final poll, where the upload data has been erased, given that the file error status is contained within the erased data, is there a way that one can reliably identify that the file upload was successful?

Alternatively, is there no reliable way to achieve either/both of the above and would a better approach be to use

> session.upload_progress.cleanup=off

and interrogate the upload data on completion, then manually manage cleanup of  session data?

Comment: Interesting.  Does the POST actually uploading the file not convey the ultimate success or failure of the upload?  What use is progress feedback once completed?  Guess I'm not fully up to speed on the topic either... What triggers the session key deletion?  Garbage collection or the upload having completed?

Comment: @ficuscr - thanks! Because APC, our existing upload cache, no longer functions as of PHP 5.5 I am coming at this from the perspective of having to migrate to the $_SESSION upload method, and I suppose am stuck in the APC head space. Yes, you are right that the POST does convey the ultimate success or failure and $_FILES contains file specific information. Since all upload information, except POST failure "reason", exists in the $_SESSION["upload progress key"] my thinking has been to access it there in a single place. Maybe actually I should rely on $_SESSION for % progress only.

Comment: I can't speak with much authority on this.  I am interested in what you find.  as an FYI: https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/php55u-pecl-apcu

Comment: @ficuscr thanks very much for the APC update info aargh!! :o)  I've got $_SESSION working with ...cleanup=off so I think we'll stick with it, warts and all (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867392/storing-php-session-upload-progress-data-in-the-database) as it is a PHP internal so I suppose has a more guaranteed life path than APC?! Thanks again for the input, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: @ficuscr - thanks again for your APCu input. Despite much debugging and many attempts at changing approach we have not achieved file upload stability using the new PHP $_SESSION approach and I am of the opinion that it is not production-ready as a file upload tool as at PHP 5.6.13. We are therefore going to try the APCu route - I will provide an update after testing as to whether or not we achieve success. (APC was always extremely reliable)

Comment: @ficuscr - APCu 4.0.7 has been now been thoroughly tested and appears to work perfectly for progress bar information, whether uploading tiny or large files. We are therefore saying goodbye to PHP $_SESSION - at least until it has matured: ie. is stable and supports database session caching (btw - I'm afraid I haven't given you +1 as your input doesn't really answer the question asked, but again thanks very much)

Comment: Thanks for following up and sharing.  Glad you ultimately did find a solid solution!